# Trying to import a CSV, MySQL giving an error

Tags: mysql

Not sure if this is really a "stack overflow" question, as it isn't immediately programmatic (I'm using PHPMyAdmin), but I am trying to import a CSV, and getting the error "invalid column count" when attempting import.

What can cause this? I merely exported from excel as a CSV - I would think that it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely because the number of columns in your CSV file is greater(or however different) than the number of columns in your database table where you are trying to import ...

Answer (score 0):

Excel is horrible at creating csv files. It often leaves trailing commas out on rows with successive blank cells.

Or it might be apostrophes in cells.

Try saving as tab delimeted text, I think I've had more luck with that.